# What books to read about lexical semantics?

Tags: semantics, lexical-semantics

I want to have a systematic understanding on [semantic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_field#cite_ref-6), [lexical semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_semantics), and [semantic change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change). Skimming at [Kate Kearns' *Semantics*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Semantics-Palgrave-Modern-Linguistics-Kearns/dp/0230232302), it seems that its focus is more about formal semantics, with topics like logic, quantifiers, predicates, tenses and thematic roles. [M. Lynne Murphy's *Semantic Relations and the Lexicon*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/semantic-relations-and-the-lexicon/C73E2724BE0DC7C7CFA69792EAAC49F3) fits my interest, but it seems to a little bit advanced for me. Is there a intermediate textbook that fits my needs? I have read cognitive psychology and cognitive linguistics, and have an introductory understanding on syntax.

Comment: Try [Frawley's _Linguistic Semantics_](https://books.google.com/books/about/Linguistic_Semantics.html?id=xeb9AQAAQBAJ), which is mostly morphological and lexical semantics. "Semantic change", however, is more a historical linguistics topic than a semantic one -- it's largely a matter of whether proposed semantic changes can plausibly fit with what historical linguists know about simultaneous phonological changes. For that, take a look at Trask's _Historical Linguistics_.

Comment: if I want to read about semantic changes, word formations, proverbs, clichés, then what fields are they?