# What are some good books on word formation and semantics?

Tags: semantics, morphology, words

I have been trying to find an accessible book for the general reader that focuses particularly on questions like:

1. How words are created? (morphology, etymology, popular PIE roots etc.)
2. How words change their meaning? (semantic changes that happen over time - broadening, narrowing, metaphorical usage etc.)

Does anyone know of a book that fits this description (that focuses more on the meaning-and-usage area of words than the formal systems involved)?
I feel like this is an interesting area even for general readers and there must be some books that elucidate on this but I wasn't able to find many popular reads.

There are [popular books](https://fivebooks.com/best-books/language-and-the-mind-lane-greene/) like 'The Language Instinct' that touches generally on many aspects of languages but I wasn't able to find any that focuses on just words. Is there a go-to book that linguists suggests for beginners in this space?

This question is the closest I could find for my requirement: [What books to read about lexical semantics?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/29860/what-books-to-read-about-lexical-semantics)

Comment: There's a set of 3 books that I used to recommend in my etymology class: Carl Darling Buck's _Dictionary of Selected Synonyms in the Principal Indo-European Languages_ ([available in pb](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/D/bo23850326.html)), Lewis Thomas's _Et Cetera, Et Cetera; Notes of a Word Watcher_, and Calvert Watkins' _The American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots_. To them I would add Larry Trask's [_Historical Linguistics_,](https://langwiki.org/images/4/41/Trasks_Historical_Linguistics_-_McColl_M.pdf) which explains everything very well.

Comment: Have you tried https://reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/index?